# PHP Binance API Price Problem Auto Calculate

Tags: php, binance

I'm using PHP Binance API. I make a limit order succesfuly.
For Example;

```
$quantity = 1500000;
$price = 0.00001000;
$order = $api->buy("SHIBUSDT", $quantity, $price);
```

But i don't want use quantity value. I want give a price and it must be calculate coin quantity.
For example;

```
$price = 0.00001000;
$quantity = 100 BNB or USDT;
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Does this help? https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ref_math.asp

Comment: This is not answer to my question :)

Answer (score 0):

It is rare that Binance offers us the quoteOrderQty option only for spot and not for margin, this would save many of us a lot of headaches; In order to calculate the amount to buy of your base asset you need the market price which you could consult with this entry Binance API Documentation, Once you have the price, divide the amount of BUSD you want to buy by the price you obtained and obtain the amount of your asset. For example, suppose you want to buy 2.5BUSD when the price of ETH is 1,500BUSD, then you would have 2.5 / 1,500 = 0.0016666666666667ETH , you would have to apply the stepsize filter to this amount, which you can consult with the GET /api/v3/exchangeInfo entry in the filters field, which in the case of ETHBUSD is 0.0001, which means that your amount would have to be truncated to 4 decimals remaining 0.0016ETH

Correction since the minimum that can be purchased must be greater than 10USDT this example does not apply with 2.5USDT otherwise you would have an error when placing the order so just change the value for 25USDT hehe